# Publishing React native app to Galaxy Stores?

Tags: android, react-native, samsung-galaxy

Considering I want to publish my Play Store app onto Samsung Galaxy Store.

I see this Doc https://developer.samsung.com/iap/programming-guide/submit-the-app-to-galaxy-store.html  Mention IAP integration.

But I can not find out Is It mandatory or not. Is It possible to upload without Samsung IAP?

Can I use same .apk or .aap file to upload on Galaxy Store?